# Notify specific user

Tags: laravel, sockets, redis

I'm trying to make a notification system, but I don't know why the code not working... The redis shoots the event, and the event is received... On the "node server.js in CMD" returns:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test>node socket.js
Listening on Port 3000
{"message":"teste","user":1} //returns when publish redis in controller.
```

Controller:

```
public function fire(){
        $redis = LRedis::connection();

    $data = ['message' => 'teste', 'user' => 1];

           if($redis->publish('message', json_encode($data))){
               return response()->json(['sucesss' => 1]);
            } else {
               return response()->json(['error' => 0]);
            }

           }
```

Template.blade.php:

```
<script>
   var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
   //console.log(socket); IS CONNECTED...

socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

socket.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('message', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log(message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Console.log

> Returns nothing...

If you help me to make work, how I can notify specific user? Example, user 1 creat a link, a link is commented by user 2, the user 1 be notified...

Comment: Outside of the scope of the question, but I'd really recommend you use Laravel's `broadcasting` on the backend (instead of Redis core classes) and `Laravel Echo` on the frontend (instead of socket.io core classes). It's a great wrapper and supports both Redis and socket.io